# Excel VBA skips a lot of occurrences

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Workbook with 6 Sheets. I am walking through them with For Each. And the task is: 
1) Walk though every cell with specified Range

2) If cell is not empty AND contains ONLY number THEN  add to the end of the cell " мм". Otherwise SKIP this cell.

But in fact, script does it good only for first sheet (Worksheet). It does no changes to other sheets. I don't know why this happens. I think, that there is some error or mistake in the code, but I double-checked it and everything seems to be correct. Help me please :)

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog
Dim r As Range
Dim rr As Range
Dim rrrrrr As Range
Dim cell As Range
k = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)

For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If xWs.Name Like "Worksheet" Then
        Set r = Range("FA2:FA" & k)
        For Each cell0 In r
            If IsEmpty(cell0.Value) = False And IsNumeric(cell0.Value) = True Then
                cell0.Value = cell0.Value & " мм"
            End If
        Next
        'xWs.Columns(41).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

    If xWs.Name Like "Worksheet 1" Then
        Set rr = Range("AG2:AG" & k)
        For Each cell1 In rr
            If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) = False And IsNumeric(cell1.Value) Then

                cell1.Value = cell1.Value & " мм"

            End If
        Next
        'xWs.Columns(126).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

    If xWs.Name Like "Worksheet 5" Then
        Set rrrrrr = Range("FR2:FR" & k)
        For Each cell5 In rrrrrr
            If IsEmpty(cell5.Value) = False And IsNumeric(cell5.Value) Then

                cell5.Value = cell5.Value & " мм"

            End If
        Next
    End If

    xWs.SaveAs xDir & "\" & xWs.Name, xlCSV, local:=True

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sets of statements need to be adjusted to correct sheet references. Current code will always look at active sheet and the range reference is not qualified.

`Set r = Range("FA2:FA" & k)`

`Set r = xWs.Range("FA2:FA" & k)`

Comment: In addition, this needs to be inside of your loop and be fully qualified. `k = xWs.Cells(xWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten-up and utilize your code a lot.

First, your `k = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` trying to get the last row, needs to be inside the `For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` , since the last row will be different for each worksheet.

Second, instead of multiple `If`s, you can use `Select Case`.

Third, there is no need to have 3 different objects for Range, like `r`, `rr`, and `rrr`. The same goes for `cell0`, `cell1` and `cell5`, you can use just one `r` and `cell`.

The only thing different inside your `If` (my `Select Case`) is the range you set `r`. The rest, looping through `r.Cells` is the same for all 3 criterias, so you can take this part outside the loop, and have it only once.

**Modifed Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim k As Long

Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)

For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' it's safer to use ThisWorkbook is you reffer to the worksheets inside the workbook which thid code resides
    With xWs
        ' getting the last row needs to be inside the loop
        k = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set r = Nothing ' reset Range Object

        Select Case .Name
            Case "Worksheet"
                Set r = .Range("FA2:FA" & k)
                'xWs.Columns(41).EntireColumn.Delete

            Case "Worksheet 1"
                Set r = .Range("AG2:AG" & k)
                'xWs.Columns(126).EntireColumn.Delete

            Case "Worksheet 5"
                Set r = .Range("FR2:FR" & k)

        End Select

        ' check if r is not nothing (it passed one of the 3 Cases in the above select case)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In r
                If IsEmpty(cell.Value) = False And IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                    cell.Value = cell.Value & " мм"
                End If
            Next cell
        End If

        .SaveAs xDir & "\" & .Name, xlCSV, Local:=True
    End With

Next xWs

End Sub
```